# How to get column names and column types from Hibernate ScrollableResults

Tags: java, hibernate

I am generating a report using Hibernate.

Constructing SQL from various table joins and querying using `Hibernate scrollable results`.

Below is the sample code:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from A, B where A.id= B.Val");
ScrollableResults results  = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

I want to know all the column names and column types before generating an Excel report.

How to achieve this with `Hibernate scrollable results`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364531/bulk-reading-of-data-in-hibernate-using-scrollable-result-set

Comment: Don't know about the column type but You can do something like  `query.results()`. It will return a list of maps, a map per row. Each map would map column name to an object corresponding to the column value for the given row.

Comment: Please look into the following example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418500/get-table-column-names-in-hibernate

Comment: Here the column list doesn't belong to any single entity. Columns are from multiple table/entity joins. Above examples are for all columns in a single table